# JSON Array & Parse Response

Tags: android, json, jsonp

Android Can u anyone please show a sample for... (Android)
1) How to get a data from a URL response using JSON?
2) How to parse that response to append in another URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you understand german, this is a great tutorial:

http://andforge.net/2010/serverkommunikation-android-rest-json/

But in english there are also good tutorials, like .e.g. this two:

http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/?ca=drs-

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.xyz.com/services/json";
   String line,response;
   conn=(HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);      
   wr=new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
   wr.write(data);
   wr.flush();
   rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
   response = "";
   while((line=rd.readLine())!=null)
   {
    response=response+line;
   }
   wr.close();
   rd.close();
   obj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Now you can use different functions like `obj.getString`, `obj.getJSONArray`, `obj.getJSONObject` etc to parse the object.

Comment: Thankyou prateek, can i ask u something specifically

Comment: I have created a login screen and written like If i press login button, it need to connect to an URL, it returning a message in webview that status code = 0, with session key. Means its successfully logged in. Now i need to get the response, check that status code if == 0; then move it to next screen, when i am moving to next screen it need to append that session key in next screens URL. all this using JSON.. do you have any idea?

Comment: Jhon can you post the "obj" value you are getting after hitting the URL? Then only I can answer how to extract the session id from it and then append it to the other URL.